# Comparação de char, ignorando o case sensitive

Tags: c, string, comparação

A proposta é criar um programa que compara as **n** primeiras posições dos dois vetores e retorna dizendo se são ou não iguais. Até aí tudo bem, mas eu não sei como posso ignorar o *case sensitive*.

Aqui está o que fiz até agora:

```
//Questão 7
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 5

int memcpy(char s1[], char s2[], int n);

int main()
{
    char s1_m[MAX]={'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}, s2_m[MAX]={'a', 'b', 'c', 'D', 'E'};
    int n_m;

    printf("quantos caracteres serao verificados(max 5)\n> "); scanf("%d", &n_m); fflush(stdin);

    printf("os %d primeiros caracteres dos dois vetores %s iguais", n_m, memcpy(s1_m, s2_m, n_m)?"sao":"nao sao");
    return 0;
}

int memcpy(char s1[], char s2[], int n)
{
    int i, contador=0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(s1[i]==s2[i])
            contador++;
        else
            break;
    }

    if(contador==n)
        i=1;
    else
        i=0;

    return i;
}
```

Comment: A resposta postada resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução apresentada foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que ela é satisfatória. Também pode votar em toda e qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo. Aceitar e votar são coisas distintas.

Answer (score 6):

Basta usar a função `tolower()` para pegar tudo minúsculo. Aproveitei e melhorei algumas coisas, por exemplo dar uma nome mais significativo para a função e que não sobrepõe uma existente em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 5

int comparacao(char s1[], char s2[], int n) {
    int contador = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (tolower(s1[i]) == tolower(s2[i])) contador++;
        else break;
    }
    return contador == n;
}

int main() {
    char s1_m[MAX] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}, s2_m[MAX] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'D', 'E'};
    int n_m;
    printf("quantos caracteres serao verificados(max 5)\n> "); scanf("%d", &n_m);
    printf("os %d primeiros caracteres dos dois vetores %ssao iguais", n_m, comparacao(s1_m, s2_m, n_m) ? "" : "nao ");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5vQVJ4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/czkycipd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/CaseSensitive.c).

Pode simplificar ainda mais a comparação:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < n && tolower(s1[i]) == tolower(s2[i]); i++);
return i == n;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9ZxbPR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cmwnovsq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/CaseSensitive2.c).

Se não quiser usar a pronta a função é mais ou menos isto:

```
int tolower(int c) {
    if (c <= 'Z' && c >= 'A') return c + 32
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Eu tinha a ideia de que se eu usasse o tolower ou o toupper, ele modificaria o vetor, mas testei aqui no Code::Blocks e está funcionando perfeitamente!